# Why RabbitMq use only one consumer at application start?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

Here is my RabbitMq config

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(4);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(4);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    }

}
```

Here is the listener

```
@Component
public class Listener {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "FirstQueue")
    public void processFirstQueue(String message) {
        System.out.println("FIRST-QUEUE " + message);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "SecondQueue", concurrency = "4-4")
    public void processSecondQueue(String message, Channel channel) {
        System.out.println("SECOND-QUEUE " + message + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
```

Here is queue details

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

And there are logs

```
2021-06-22 12:55:45.811  INFO 1620 --- [           main] com.rabbit.demo.RabbitDemoApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-06-22 12:55:46.594  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-06-22 12:55:46.616  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-06-22 12:55:46.617  INFO 1620 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2021-06-22 12:55:46.753  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-06-22 12:55:46.753  INFO 1620 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 882 ms
2021-06-22 12:55:46.951  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-06-22 12:55:47.166  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-06-22 12:55:47.168  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: localhost:5672
2021-06-22 12:55:47.196  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: connectionFactory#4b6d92e:0/SimpleConnection@11d045b4 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 57952]
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
2021-06-22 12:55:47.239  INFO 1620 --- [           main] com.rabbit.demo.RabbitDemoApplication    : Started RabbitDemoApplication in 1.676 seconds (JVM running for 2.381)
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
THERE IS RUNTIME SENDING STARTS
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-1
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-2
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-4
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-1
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-2
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-4
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-1
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-2
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-4
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-1
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-2
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-4
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-1
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-2
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-4
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-1
SECOND-QUEUE Hi org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-2
```

All the messages before title "THERE IS RUNTIME SENDING STARTS" were put to the queue while the application was stopped. Messages after that title were put to the queue while application was running.
I dont understand, why only one thread was used to procces all the messages, which were put to the queue before the application was started? How can I fix it?

Comment: There are 4 threads. Maybe you can not send message concurrently.

Comment: You can see that only RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#1-3 works with messages, which were put to the queue while app was stopped. Others threads start when I send messages while app running. I send messages via rabbit-management UI

Comment: Saying hi is too fast to catch for multithreaded environment. Actually if you have put some thread sleep then test it. You can stop app and start with thread sleep.